# Google chrome headless is rendering html as mobile view

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, google-chrome-headless

I am using google-chrome headless in laravel to convert HTML to PDF, however, it is rendering as a mobile view instead of rendering as a large screen-sized device.

My code:

```
$content = '.......';
$html = view('pdf_wrapper', compact('content'))->render();


// Generating a unique temporary file name for the HTML content
$tempHtmlFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'chrome_html_') . '.html';
$tempPdfFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'chrome_pdf_') . '.pdf';

// Save the rendered HTML content to the temporary file
file_put_contents($tempHtmlFile, $html);

// Path to the Chrome executable, can be adjusted server environment
$chromePath = '/usr/bin/google-chrome';

// Construct the command to run Chrome in headless mode
$command = sprintf(
    '%s --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --print-to-pdf=%s --window-size=1920,1080 --disable-mobile-emulation --disable-application-cache --force-device-scale-factor=1 --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/112.0.5615.165 Safari/537.36" %s',
    escapeshellcmd($chromePath),
    escapeshellarg($tempPdfFile),
    escapeshellarg($tempHtmlFile)
);

// Execute the command
exec($command);

// Option 1: Serve the PDF to the user
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
readfile($tempPdfFile);

@unlink($tempHtmlFile); // Remove the temporary HTML file
@unlink($tempPdfFile); // Remove the temporary PDF file after serving/saving it

exit();
```

already tried with `window-size`, `disable-mobile-emulation`, `user-agent`. Additionally, I have tried to manipulate this viewport as well. Tested with both of these one by one, but still not working.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1920">
```

It is printing the page just like in mobile view, for example, `com-md-3` is showing 100% width instead of showing 25%. CSS working fine with color and styles everything, it looks like it is rendering as mobile devices.

Steps to reproduce:

`/usr/bin/google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=output.pdf --window-size="1920,1080" https://www.getbootstrap.com/`

Comment: Which version of chrome?

Comment: How can i find it? If you are asking chrome version its 120 on my system, however, in user-agent i have used 112

Comment: Read this doc as it talks about an old and new headless https://developer.chrome.com/docs/chromium/new-headless

Comment: I tried with both =old as well as =nee no difference

Comment: See if you can find documentation on "chrome command line switches". For example, your use of `--window-size=1920,1080` is incorrect. But instead of trying this and that, locate the documentation so that you can become informed on the correct way. Approach every problem this way.

Comment: @KJ it's not working like that you could test it directly from command line as well, I have tested with this

`/usr/bin/google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=output.pdf --window-size="1936,2014" https://www.getbootstrap.com/`

but still not working

Comment: could you please try this command, `/usr/bin/google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=output.pdf --window-size="1936,2014" https://www.getbootstrap.com/` and this was the sample output I got https://tmpfiles.org/dl/3993359/output.pdf I think with the sample output you might get and idea about what I am referring

Comment: @kJ I am not sure if i get your point, could you please suggest any workaround? I believe you have understood my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Chromium unattended printing is limited to just enough to maintain.

```
Brave/Chrome/Edge/Others --headless --screenshot=path/file.PNG (default 800px,600px) [--window-size="X,Y"] URL (Https|file://path/filename)
```

**NOTE** even "Window Size" may not be as expected so for a square 1920x1920 PNG I have to use `--window-size="1936,2014"` because Chrome trims it in both directions as if in a frame border.

For PDF there is **only default 612 pt X 812 pt** (American portrait "Letter" size). That is all, unless edited at either end. Note Edge Browser   incorrectly says size 288 × 373 mm (portrait), so it is correct about orientation but gets its Metric Units ratio 1.333% wrong !

```
Brave/Chrome/Edge/Others --headless --print-to-pdf=path/file.PDF URL (Https|file://path/filename)
```

Other options are available for other functions (such as, you can switch off the top and bottom margin head & foot overprint). See the unofficial list at https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

If the site has set a CSS design for "Media Print Size" it is honoured. So one work around is to edit a copy of the HTML by replacing `<body>` with something like :-

```
<style> @media print { @page { margin: 0; size: 1920px 1024px ; } body { margin: 0; } } </style><body>
```

The other alternative is to use  a robotic browser such as puppeteer. Which is allowed to add preferences, like Landscape and other size controls, as if the user had made those choices.

Comment: no, it doesn't work as well, however, as a workaround, I override the bootstrap CSS class like col-md-1, col-md-2, col-md-3, .... col-lg-1, col-lg-2,.... with respective percentage